# autoLoad: false is ignored in ExtJs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a MVC application. One of the stores is defined like so:

```
Ext.define('Instructions.store.InstructionsObjectTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires: ['Instructions.model.InstructionsObjectTreeModel'],
    model: 'Instructions.model.InstructionsObjectTreeModel',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'controller/InstructionsHandler.php',
        node: 'id',
        extraParams: {
            action: 'getInstructionsObjectTree'
        }
    },
    root: {
        text: 'Objects',
        id: 'src',
        root: true,
        expanded: true
    }
});
```

But, as far as I can see in the console, `autoLoad` is ignored. I also tried old suggestions to use

```
root:{
    loaded: true
}
```

in my treepanel definition, but it does not help either. So, how to fix it?

Comment: autoLoad will be by default false  
so u don't need to add it in store definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have read the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-autoLoad) too closely (which is usually good), following too many references and even looking at the examples. Please report at the sencha forum severe bugs in the docs' examples.

> It's important to note that Tree Stores will
>   load regardless of autoLoad's value **if expand is set to true on the root node.**

*This part of the docs is completely correct.* All other (including code samples) are wrong.

```
expand: false
```

should solve the issue, as per this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15gc).

```
expanded: false
```

does nothing, albeit used nearly everywhere else.

Comment: I also found out that `loaded: true` specified inside root part of store definition also works.

Comment: BTW. My treepanel is inside `fieldset` (which is inside some panel with numerous other fields). This `fieldset` has property `layout: "fit"`, the `treepanel` itself has property `scrollable: true`, however when the store is loaded, I see no scrollbar. Don't you know what may be the reason? `ExtJS 6` bug?

Comment: Not sure, possibly the fieldset's parent container overflows. If this is not the solution, make a fiddle and a new question.

Comment: Sir, what do you mean by "parent container overflows"? Some special property?

Comment: I mean that one parent container of the fieldset may be a vbox panel without scrollbar, where the fieldset continues below the visible area. The difference is easy to spot, because the fieldset has a bottom border which would not be visible.

Comment: @jacobian I solved that issue until the component gets rendered, for example:      
`
listeners: {               
                show: function(tree) {
                    tree.setStyle({
                        'overflow-y': 'scroll'
                    });
                }
            } 
`